# Setting the alignment of dynamic values in a layout

Tags: android, textview, text-alignment

Consider the xml file with the following textview layout:

[image]

I am trying to set the alignment of my this textview whose values are coming dynamically such that it should be:

> **One:24**
>
> **Two:6000**

The problem the layout is coming like this:

[image]

How to align it properly?

My xml is having **visibility:gone** set for `One:` and `Two:` text views. Then in my java file, I am doing like so:

```
one.setText("One:"+entries.get("one"));
two.setText("Two:"+entries.get("two"));

if(entries.get("type").equals("OneType"))
{
one.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
two.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
else
{
 one.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
 two.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

UPDATE:

The xml file relevant code:

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/passedlayout"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="right"
android:orientation="vertical"
>


<TextView
android:id="@+id/one"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
android:visibility="gone"
android:textColor="#000000"
android:textStyle="bold"/>

<TextView
android:id="@+id/two"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
android:visibility="gone"
android:textColor="#000000"
android:textStyle="bold"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

UPDATE:

I have multiple such rows for a single layout. Setting the gravity to left worked for the single layout.
However for more than one rows having varying digits, the layout again gets disturbed
like this-

Layout1:

> **One:24**
>
> **Two:6000**

Layout2:

> **One:0**
>
> **Two:0**

You see that **One:** and **Two:** of `Layout1` are not aligned with **One:** and **Two:** of `Layout2`.

Comment: are you talking about aligning the one and two text ?

Comment: trick will be in your layout, so post it too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
android:gravity="right"
```

to

```
android:gravity="left"
```

in the `LinearLayout` with id `passedlayout`

Comment: This is fine for a single layout. But I have multiple such layouts. So if one layout has single digit value and the other one below it is having two or more digit values, the alignment again fails.

Comment: Which one is having problem Layout1 or Layout2?

Comment: See the update again carefully. I have only one Layout which is repeating in a loop such that for different rows: row1, row2, row3,etc.

Comment: So the simple solution will be to set a default width for your layout, if you want more perfection you can calculate the highest width of text  and apply it to all views!

Comment: android width and height ok. But what if I set `android:layout_weight`. Will it do more easily?

Comment: Setting `android:layout_weight` for linear layout worked like a charm.

Comment: ya setting android:layout_weight is also preferable   depending on your parent view of Linear layout, but make sure that you test it on all devices to make sure that it does not omit your long numbers!